# Time.zone undefined after requiring acitve_support/all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This irb session will demonstrate the problem:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'active_support/all'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> Time.zone.now
NoMethodError: undefined method `now' for nil:NilClass
    from (irb):2
    from /Users/jg/.rbenv/versions/2.2.4/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

I have the latest version of `activesupport` installed, and am following the example from the docs here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html

What could be causing this error?

### UPDATE

Examining this closer in `pry`, it appears that `Time` is getting monkey-patched successfully by `activesupport`, but the `zone` is not being set.  I think it may just be that the user (or rails) is responsible for setting it, whereas I'd assumed it was set by default to the local zone.

Comment: It seems like your using an old version of rails. Try require 'rubygems' and then require 'active_support/all'

Comment: why would rails matter here?  it's only the activesupport gem that i'm using.  as i said, it's the latest version.  `gem list | grep 'active'` returns `activesupport (5.0.0.1, 4.2.1)`

Comment: What version of ruby are you running?

Comment: `ruby 2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155) [x86_64-darwin15]`

Comment: To answer your question using require 'active_support/all' indicated an old version of either ruby or rails.  Dump your irb session and reload it and just try Time.zone.now

Comment: Same error if I do that.  Note that `zone` is not a class method on `Time`.  But according to the docs linked in my OP, it is added as one by activesupport.  There's no reason to think it would work without the `require 'active_support/all'`.

Comment: This ( http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html ) seems to indicate that you will need to set the time zone if your not using Rails Eg.. Time.zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'

Comment: Yeah, see my update.  If you want to put that as an answer I'll accept.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: can u try `Time.now.zone`  ?